# Is there a way to install a nuget package without creating a csproj?

Tags: azure, powershell, nuget

I'm looking through the dotnet CLI and nuget CLI to see if there's anything which will download a package from a feed, without having to do a restore against a csproj file.

The reason for this is I have a pipeline which needs to download a nuget package to use something inside it, but I've no application so no need for a csproj.

Is it possible in the command line to simply say: **"Download this nuget package to this location?"**

Needs to be via nuget because the nuget feed is already configured with an ADO token (trying to avoid having to manage credentials).

Comment: Sorry, this is probably more helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference

Comment: Embarrassing.. not sure how I missed the install command, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the nuget CLI ([download here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads))

Once you have downloaded the CLI, you can install  packages like so:

`nuget install NewtonSoft.Json`

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-exe-cli-reference) is the reference I used

Comment: you can also add `-Source` argument to nail it to specific package source.